# What is asynchronous and Is Reactive Programming must be asynchronous?

Tags: asynchronous, reactive-programming

In wiki:

> In computing, reactive programming is a declarative programming paradigm concerned with data streams and the propagation of change. With this paradigm, it's possible to express static (e.g., arrays) or dynamic (e.g., event emitters) data streams with ease, and also communicate that an inferred dependency within the associated execution model exists, which facilitates the automatic propagation of the changed data flow.

So, Reactive Programming is just a declarative programming paradigm concerned with data streams. But why reactive programming are asynchronous programming in many circumstances?

Comment: Define what you think asynchronous means, because in my definition, the **only** way to do reactive programming is asynchronously.  The alternative is constantly condition checking.  If possible show code to contrast the two definitions.

Comment: The processing of a certain event in FRP is (usually) _pure_ and _synchronous_. However, calling side effects are usually asynchronous and since the system is event driven it results in a system where the (asynchronous) effectful actions and its associated eventual result are loosely coupled. In that system, there is no notion between a certain action and its associated result. There are just events, which enter the system. You may perceive it as asynchronously, since the event was a result of calling a side effect earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous programming is the user of execution that occurs off of the main execution thread. This trends to consist of:

1. defining some piece of work to do (eg: making a remote call)
2. 'submiting' it to be executed if the main thread, which immediately returns an object such as a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), or a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to the main thread. This object can be used to poll and retrieve the result of the asynchronous computation.
3. Yielding a result from the previously returned object

This allows us to define execution logic as data and pass this around to be explicitly executed at the right time, or some variable number of times.

This works well with Reactive programming because this paradigm is declarative. The programmer declares the data structure and data transformations within their program, and the framework handles reacting to changes by applying the necessary transformations.

By writing data transformations as asynchronous code, the reactive framework can coordinate which transformations need to be performed and manage internally the invocation of your asynchronous functions and chaining of their results.

Answer (score 1):

**Asynchronous programming** just means the main thread can delegate a job to be done elsewhere, and it can do other stuff whilst waiting for the job’s result to come in. Often main thread is notified of the result in form of outer world calling a callback function provided by the main thread.

> Sidenote: the contrary, or the world without “async” would be like the main thread delegates the job, then sits there doing nothing but just waiting for a result, most likely busy polling “is it done?”. Aka the main thread is *blocked*.

**Reactive programming** means the main thread delegates a subscription job somewhere (although doesn’t have to be other threads, could be itself) requesting “when this event occurs, notify me by calling this callback function so that I can REACT to that event. By the way, that callback function I just gave you is technically my REACTION”.

Sound familiar? The two ideas *structurally resemble* each other, might as well be seen as the same concept viewed from different angles.

---

I must say, you are technically *correct* that reactive patterns could still be used without async involve, e.g.

```
fromArray([1, 2, 3]).subscribe(
  item => reactOnArrayItem(item)
)
```

But what’s the point? `.subscribe` here is practically the same as `.map` with the drawback that you don't have a return value, which just complicates things.

For sync process, you're better off using vanilla for-loop. The reactive pattern only makes sense when async process is involved, because you simply CANNOT for-loop a thing that’s not yet ready.

Or can you?

Imagine a world where the main thread MUST block on not-yet-ready future events and stuff, wouldn’t it make perfect sense to also allow for-loop over future stuff? Then in this world, there’s indeed no place for reactive patterns. Because we are blocked anyway, why the rush, why even `.subscribe` when you can for-loop and chill?

Now you see the two are closely related. Reactive programming is born out of the necessity of elegantly orchestrating async stuff.

Comment: This is a great answer explaining how reactive programming is related to asynchronous programming!

Answer (score 0):

In layman terms, **Reactive programming** is "**pull based**", which basically means, data will be received when the client application is ready to process more data instead of the server just pushing everything as soon as it can.
This is useful when you have an API that produces a large amount of data and your browser just hangs while trying to load everything all at once, in this case if you switch to reactive approach, the browser will show the data is can before fetching more.

Asynchronous programming exactly what it sounds like, you send a request and attach a **callback function** to that request and move on to doing other things. When the request is processed, it will trigger the callback function attached. There is no constant back and forth between the client and server like there is in reactive approach.

Both are useful and have their own usecases, we must identify which approach is better in what scenario.

Comment: Why would you classify reactive programming as pull-based? It’s clearly push-based.